# Base64 encode image in visual composer WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, image

I try to get a base64 in my img src like this: `<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,etc..."/>` into my WordPress website through the visual composer in **text mode**. It's all working fine when I save it but when I edit it again the `src` attribute is just gone. The image does get displayed but the code disappears when I try to edit it. When I update it without editing anything it just saves `<img />` without anything in it. So no image is shown. This only happens when my src starts with the standard base64. It stays when I just throw in a URL. What is going wrong here and how do I fix this?

**Edit:**

I use text block element which I would like to keep this way cause Im using a json plugin.

When I inspect it, it removes the: `image/jpg` part.

Comment: Are you using Visual composer image or are you using Visual composer HTML block?

Comment: @YahyaHHussein block. The full image source comes from json which I insert with json content importer but I know thats not the problem since it just echos the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use Visual Composer backend editor and add the img src code through 'Raw HTML' element.

I tried replicating your issues using this encoded image code

https://jsfiddle.net/casiano/xadvz/

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64"/>
```

but I never faced that issue.

Comment: This is not gonna work since I am using a plugin to add json on my page. It outputs the plugin tags as raw text.